# sql injection in sqlite full text search

Tags: python, sqlite, full-text-search

consider sqlite3 fts4 table

```
c.execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE docs USING fts4(content)")
```

Is the following safe from sql injection where txt contains a string?

I am not sure if parameterised query is safe or not,since there is only one parameter txt which is a string.

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH (?)",(txt,))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe from SQL injection; that is what the SQL parameter is ***for***, to escape and quote `txt` properly.

If you were to use string formatting (`"... MATCH ('%s')" % txt` or `" ... MATCH ('{}')".format(txt)`, *then* you'd be opening a SQL injection vector, as you wouldn't be escaping meta characters in `txt`.